# Angular Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following code in angularjs

```
angular.module('app').directive('directiveName', function ($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            $http({
                method: 'JSONP',
                url: attributes.resource
            }).then(function (response) {
                scope.rows = response.data;
                console.log(scope.rows);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

and it keeps returning me following error.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your response is returning HTML. It commonly happens if the URL is a 404

Comment: Such as, to pick something completely at random, the text being returned by that URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is commonly found when script expect json or javascript but the response is **HTML**. Try checking your response, it most probably is HTML.

You can check in chromes network tab, click on the URL in question and you can see a preview of the response.